# Mouse Movement in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

i am trying to move mouse cursor using finger coordinate in opencv. i am not able to scale it to entire screen size which 1366*768. my webcam resolution is 640*480. my mouse pointer moves only to half of the screen. i do not know why.

this is the function call:

```
Mouse_Move(((1366*mouse_pointer.x)/640),((768*mouse_pointer.y)/480));
```

and this is the implementation:

```
void Mouse_Move(DWORD dx,DWORD dy)
{

DWORD event=0;

event = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

mouse_event(event, dx*65535/Get_ScreenWidth(), dy*65535/Get_ScreenHight(), 0, 0);

}
```

this is my code segment. 
mouse_pointer.x and mouse_pointer.y are the coordinate of my fore-finger.

Comment: What is `mouse_event()`? Doesn't look like an OpenCV function. Actually nothing here seems remotely related to OpenCV.

Comment: If you're working on a windows platform, setCursorPos(,) under Windows.h should serve the purpose